# Calculate the difference between every two columns

Tags: r

I have a data frame named bias_correc with observations as x columns and forecast values as y columns. The data frame, shown below contains observations and forecasts for different regions so the columns do have similar names, and I would like to calculate the forecast deviation for each location i.e. coast, at each time step.

I know how to do this manually by creating a new column with simple subtraction by each set of location columns

```
bias_correc$Coast <- bias_correc$Coast.y- bias_correct$Coast.x
```

but I would like to do this through an apply function or loop if possible so that each set of location columns is calculated and dumped into this data frame or a new one.

I am familiar with the seq function and have used it in the past, but I'm not sure how to wrap it into an apply function or loop so that the difference of every two columns by location is calculated.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
bias_correc <-
structure(list(Forecast_day = c(8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8), Forecast_date = structure(c(17555, 
17556, 17557, 17558, 17559, 17560), class = "Date"), DeliveryDate = structure(c(17563, 
17564, 17565, 17566, 17567, 17568), class = "Date"), HourEnding = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Coast.x = c(60.8, 62.6, 50.5, 56.8, 58.9, 
59.4), Coast.y = c(58.5, 51, 46.7, 49.7, 49.3, 48.2), East.x = c(56, 
52, 43, 47, 43.5, 52.5), East.y = c(56.5, 43.5, 41.5, 43.5, 43, 
43), FarWest.x = c(50, 41, 45.5, 49.5, 35.5, 49.5), FarWest.y = c(46.5, 
34.5, 36.5, 38, 41.5, 39), North.x = c(49, 34.5, 34.5, 39.5, 
24.5, 34.5), North.y = c(49.5, 32, 33, 38, 38.5, 34.5), NorthCentral.x = c(57.5, 
44.75, 45.5, 52.75, 35.75, 38.5), NorthCentral.y = c(54, 37.5, 
39.75, 42, 42.5, 40), SouthCentral.x = c(56.5, 53.5, 51.5, 48.5, 
53.5, 56), SouthCentral.y = c(56, 43.5, 43, 45, 45, 45), Southern.x = c(60.4, 
63.6, 55, 61.8, 64, 65.6), Southern.y = c(58.4, 52.8, 50.4, 54, 
54.4, 53.6), West.x = c(57.6, 42, 43.4, 51.8, 32.6, 45.2), West.y = c(49.6, 
34.6, 36.8, 38.6, 40.4, 36.2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), .Names = c("Forecast_day", "Forecast_date", "DeliveryDate", 
"HourEnding", "Coast.x", "Coast.y", "East.x", "East.y", "FarWest.x", 
"FarWest.y", "North.x", "North.y", "NorthCentral.x", "NorthCentral.y", 
"SouthCentral.x", "SouthCentral.y", "Southern.x", "Southern.y", 
"West.x", "West.y"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we do some string manipulation on the column names, it should be fairly straightforward.

```
# find column names ending in ".x"
var_names <- names(bias_correc)[grepl(pattern = ".x",
                                      x = names(bias_correc),
                                      fixed = TRUE)]
# replace ".x" with "" (blank)
var_names <- gsub(pattern = ".x", replacement = "", x = var_names, fixed = TRUE)
# subtract y and x
(diff_table <- bias_correc[paste0(var_names, ".y")] - bias_correc[paste0(var_names, ".x")])

  Coast.y East.y FarWest.y North.y NorthCentral.y SouthCentral.y Southern.y West.y
1    -2.3    0.5      -3.5     0.5          -3.50           -0.5       -2.0   -8.0
2   -11.6   -8.5      -6.5    -2.5          -7.25          -10.0      -10.8   -7.4
3    -3.8   -1.5      -9.0    -1.5          -5.75           -8.5       -4.6   -6.6
4    -7.1   -3.5     -11.5    -1.5         -10.75           -3.5       -7.8  -13.2
5    -9.6   -0.5       6.0    14.0           6.75           -8.5       -9.6    7.8
6   -11.2   -9.5     -10.5     0.0           1.50          -11.0      -12.0   -9.0

cbind(bias_correc, setNames(diff_table, var_names)) # bind back to original table
```

Comment: This works great! Thank you. I thought about trying something with the column names, but that was a bit too ambitious with my skill level. However, I definitely understand what you did here and learned quite a bit. Thanks again.

Comment: glad I was able to help. I edited my answer after you accepted to include a part which `cbind`s the result back to the original data with correct names

Answer (score 2):

You can extract specific columns using `grep` and iterate over data.frame performing subtraction using `apply` family.

Code:

```
cNamesID <- grep("\\.[x|y]$", colnames(bias_correc))
cNames <- unique(sub("\\.[x|y]$", "", colnames(bias_correc)[cNamesID]))
cbind(bias_correc[, -cNamesID],
      sapply(cNames, function(x) 
             bias_correc[, paste0(x, ".y")] - bias_correc[, paste0(x, ".x")]))
```

Result:

> ```
> Forecast_day Forecast_date DeliveryDate HourEnding Coast East FarWest North NorthCentral SouthCentral Southern  West
> 1            8    2018-01-24   2018-02-01          1  -2.3  0.5    -3.5   0.5        -3.50         -0.5     -2.0  -8.0
> 2            8    2018-01-25   2018-02-02          1 -11.6 -8.5    -6.5  -2.5        -7.25        -10.0    -10.8  -7.4
> 3            8    2018-01-26   2018-02-03          1  -3.8 -1.5    -9.0  -1.5        -5.75         -8.5     -4.6  -6.6
> 4            8    2018-01-27   2018-02-04          1  -7.1 -3.5   -11.5  -1.5       -10.75         -3.5     -7.8 -13.2
> 5            8    2018-01-28   2018-02-05          1  -9.6 -0.5     6.0  14.0         6.75         -8.5     -9.6   7.8
> 6            8    2018-01-29   2018-02-06          1 -11.2 -9.5   -10.5   0.0         1.50        -11.0    -12.0  -9.0
> ```

Comment: That works really well. I appreciate the cbind portion so that i can retain my time columns as well! Saving this code. Thank you.

Comment: Happy to help, this solution gives wanted output (ie, exact column names).

Answer (score 1):

Given that the names of the data frame are consistent with the `.x` and `.y` variations of the attribute names, we can do this without a loop:

```
deviation <- cbind(bias_correc[1:4], bias_correc[grep('\\.y', names(bias_correc))] -
                                     bias_correc[grep('\\.x', names(bias_correc))])
```

This gives:

```
  Forecast_day Forecast_date DeliveryDate HourEnding Coast.y East.y FarWest.y North.y NorthCentral.y SouthCentral.y Southern.y West.y
1            8    2018-01-24   2018-02-01          1    -2.3    0.5      -3.5     0.5          -3.50           -0.5       -2.0   -8.0
2            8    2018-01-25   2018-02-02          1   -11.6   -8.5      -6.5    -2.5          -7.25          -10.0      -10.8   -7.4
3            8    2018-01-26   2018-02-03          1    -3.8   -1.5      -9.0    -1.5          -5.75           -8.5       -4.6   -6.6
4            8    2018-01-27   2018-02-04          1    -7.1   -3.5     -11.5    -1.5         -10.75           -3.5       -7.8  -13.2
5            8    2018-01-28   2018-02-05          1    -9.6   -0.5       6.0    14.0           6.75           -8.5       -9.6    7.8
6            8    2018-01-29   2018-02-06          1   -11.2   -9.5     -10.5     0.0           1.50          -11.0      -12.0   -9.0
```

Comment: Super clean and fast! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A tidyverse approach:

```
library(rlang)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

nms <- bias_correc %>%
  names() %>%
  sort() %>%
  syms()

nms_x <- nms[ends_with(".x", vars = nms)]
nms_y <- nms[ends_with(".y", vars = nms)]

fn <- function (x, y) {
  quo(`-`(!!y, !!x))
}

diffs <- nms_x %>%
  map2(nms_y, fn) %>%
  set_names(nms_y)

mutate(bias_correc, !!!diffs)
```

Which returns:

```
  Forecast_day Forecast_date DeliveryDate HourEnding Coast.x Coast.y East.x East.y FarWest.x FarWest.y North.x North.y
1            8    2018-01-24   2018-02-01          1    60.8    -2.3   56.0    0.5      50.0      -3.5    49.0     0.5
2            8    2018-01-25   2018-02-02          1    62.6   -11.6   52.0   -8.5      41.0      -6.5    34.5    -2.5
3            8    2018-01-26   2018-02-03          1    50.5    -3.8   43.0   -1.5      45.5      -9.0    34.5    -1.5
4            8    2018-01-27   2018-02-04          1    56.8    -7.1   47.0   -3.5      49.5     -11.5    39.5    -1.5
5            8    2018-01-28   2018-02-05          1    58.9    -9.6   43.5   -0.5      35.5       6.0    24.5    14.0
6            8    2018-01-29   2018-02-06          1    59.4   -11.2   52.5   -9.5      49.5     -10.5    34.5     0.0
  NorthCentral.x NorthCentral.y SouthCentral.x SouthCentral.y Southern.x Southern.y West.x West.y
1          57.50          -3.50           56.5           -0.5       60.4       -2.0   57.6   -8.0
2          44.75          -7.25           53.5          -10.0       63.6      -10.8   42.0   -7.4
3          45.50          -5.75           51.5           -8.5       55.0       -4.6   43.4   -6.6
4          52.75         -10.75           48.5           -3.5       61.8       -7.8   51.8  -13.2
5          35.75           6.75           53.5           -8.5       64.0       -9.6   32.6    7.8
6          38.50           1.50           56.0          -11.0       65.6      -12.0   45.2   -9.0
```